# Problems Sending an HTTP Request Using Swift

Tags: swift, http

I'm entirely new to development in Swift or networking. I'm trying to throw something simple together that query a URL:

I'm trying to write a simple program, where I have three buttons, and each time a button is tapped, I send data to the data.sparkfun.com data stream storing service where it will store my variable "test_value"

I need to query this URL:

```
http://data.sparkfun.com/input/XGyzWVyDdEFKDE42W99r?private_key=KEYVALUE&test_value=1"
```

Here is the code I'm trying to work with unsuccessfully after reading some simple tutorials:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func ColorTwoTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Color 2")
}

@IBAction func ColorOneTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Color 1")

    let scriptUrl = "http://data.sparkfun.com/input/XGyzWVyDdEFKDE42W99r"

    let urlWithParams = scriptUrl + "?private_key=KEYVALUE&test_value=1"

    let myUrl = NSURL(string: urlWithParams);


    let task = URLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(myUrl!) {(data, response, error) in
        print(String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
    }

    task.resume()


}

@IBAction func ColorThreeTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Color 3")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

The error I get is

```
Cannot call value of non-function type 'URLSession'.
```

Thanks for any advice

Comment: try NSURLSession?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the tutorial that you've selected was written for Swift 2.x, whereas you are apparently using Swift 3.

In Swift 3, the method would be:

```
@IBAction func colorOneTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Color 1")

    let scriptUrl = "http://data.sparkfun.com/input/XGyzWVyDdEFKDE42W99r"

    let urlWithParams = scriptUrl + "?private_key=KEYVALUE&test_value=1"

    let myUrl = URL(string: urlWithParams)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: myUrl!) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("\(error)")
            return
        }

        let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("\(string)")
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Note, it's `URL`, not `NSURL`. And it's `shared`, not `sharedSession()`. Likewise `dataTaskWithURL(_:completionHandler:)` is now `dataTask(with:completionHandler:)`. I'd also suggest avoiding `!` forced unwrapping and use optional binding (e.g. `if let` or `guard let`).

---

Note, if you sending data to be stored on the server, you'd generally use `POST`:

```
@IBAction func colorOneTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Color 1")

    let urlString = "http://data.sparkfun.com/input/XGyzWVyDdEFKDE42W99r"

    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = "private_key=KEYVALUE&test_value=1".data(using: .utf8)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("\(error)")
            return
        }

        let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("\(string)")
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Note, there are tons of other little details here, too, such as needing to percent-escape the keys and values if you'll be sending anything other than `a`-`z`, `A`-`Z`, `0`-`9` and `-`, `.`, `_`, or `~` (whether in the URL of `GET` request or in the body of the `POST` request). And you'd often set the `Accept` header to let the server know in what form you're expecting the response and then write the code to parse that sort of response. Likewise, you need to set the `NSAppTransportSecurity` in the `Info.plist` if you're using `http` rather than `https`.

---

You might also want to consider using something like [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) if you don't want to get too lost in all of these details.

Answer (score 0):

Replace URLSession with NSURLSession. use a guard to check if data is nil.

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(myUrl!) {(data, response, error) in
    guard let data = data else {
        return
    }
    print(String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
}

task.resume()
```